# Angular Js Application with two different layouts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-view

I have been working on large angularJs application which have multiple modules. Problem is that now I have to include static website in that application and that website have whole different layout than my application.

I did some R&D and found some answers which were mostly dependent on angular.bootstrap

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

but my application's ng-view is declared in html tag not in body and further my layout is like mentioned below.

```
<div ui-view="header">
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container">
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
    <div class="page-sidebar-wrapper" ui-view="sidebar">
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content" ui-view="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
</div>
```

but website structure is totally different from this structure so can anyone please suggest how tackle this situation

should I use two ng-views in my index.html if yes than how can I use two ng-views while declare in html tag.

Thanks

Comment: Use `ui-router` for nested views. You can then define a single main view, 2 main states that sets the layout in that view, and sub states with sub views for each state / layout.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is like nested views? which the default router does not support so if you want to use of nested views for that you have to use third-party module.